# MySQL Index On Session Columns

Tags: mysql, indexing

Would it be a good idea to have a index on a session column in a user table? It is updated whenever someone's session changes so I'm not sure if performance would be better or worse (the table has 200k users, although maybe only 5,000-10,000 log on in a month).

A example of the query that is used to verify the logged on user would be (COOKIE.USERSESSIONID would be the session ID from the user's cookie):

```
SELECT uname,credits,coins,avatarData,verifyemail,email,lastip FROM users WHERE session = "COOKIE.USERSESSIONID"
```

Comment: are you talking about session management on database level?

Comment: Yes, as in a user being logged into a website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are considering using db session storage I would suggest you look at using the MEMORY table type.

Simply store your user id, data, last update....

Memory tables are super fast, you can clean them up by deleting rows over a specified time period.

Memory issues will occur if you store loads of data in there but managing it properly should negate that problem pretty sharpish...

Comment: Wouldn't this log every user out if the server is restarted?

Comment: @Bubby4j Yes, data is lost on every mysql restart.

Comment: If the server went down, logging people out would be the least of your worries.

Comment: Not really, the server is set up so if there is a power loss it restarts and opens the webserver and stuff, although sometimes there is mysql corruption but usually repair table fixes it.

Comment: If a server restarts then all session data would be lost regardless. Only way to maintain data in that situation is in a cookie. This is about using the right tool for the job - if you are storing session data in database then memory table is the right tool. The speed it offers negates issues with table level locking - even compared to row level locking in other table types memory tables will perform much faster.

Answer (score 0):

You need at least 1 index for the where clause, in this case session field.
Maintain a simple index isn't a hard job for the database, and you queries will be much faster since the database knows where the data is in disk.

Comment: I have a primary index for the username, but that... wait... I could have the client store the username then use something like `SELECT session FROM users WHERE uname="COOKIE.USERNAME"` then I could compare the session, this might be a quicker approach.

Comment: Or possibly `SELECT stuff FROM users WHERE uname="COOKIE.USERNAME" AND session="COOKIE.SESSIONID"`, would it first find the uname and then check if the session belongs to that username?

Comment: @Bubby4j depends on your design, if you have only 1 session per uses you can drop the "session" field and use only their userid or username